# Why HyperLink control don't get url?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke-7

I use a  HyperLink control in my page

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="btn_add_Task" Text="Create New Task" CssClass="dnnPrimaryAction"></asp:HyperLink>
```

In code behinde set it url

```
 protected void On_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            btn_add_Task.NavigateUrl = ModuleContext.EditUrl("Edit");
        }
```

But When build and run, it don't have any url in properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the EditUrl("Edit") to work, you need to make sure you have a module view with the controlkey that matches "Edit".  Here is what that looks like in your .dnn manifest file for installing the module:

```
<moduleControl>
    <controlKey>Edit</controlKey>
    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/MyModule/Edit.ascx</controlSrc>
    <controlType>Edit</controlType>
    ...
</moduleControl>
```

And it should look like this in Host > Extensions > [Edit you Extension] > Module Definitions:

[image]

Notice I have a control with "Edit" key that maps to my Edit.ascx view

Answer (score 0):

the `ModuleContet.EditUrl("Edit")`it return null because the compiler well not find the page cause there is no extension it must be like this

```
btn_add_Task.NavigateUrl = ModuleContext.EditUrl("Edit.aspx");
```